# Different ways inflate a layout

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I was trying to inflate a layout and i came across these two code.Can someone please tell me the difference between these two inflate method?
I am new to android studio and i want to learn more about this inflate method.
Also apart from these two are there any other way to inflate a layout?

```
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,int viewType){
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.movie_list_row, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}
```

and

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);
    return rowView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting a view (if need in fragment use inside of oncreate getLayoutInflater() replace the oncreateview inflater object)

```
 View v=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main2,null);
```

For getting a view for listview

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row,parent,false);
```